# MVC4-Refresh Issue:Same partial view called 3 times using foreach..loop

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am in a tricky situation,
    Scenario- There are gadgets which are to be shown in mobile site.
    2.One of the gadget is RSS which user can add multiple times for  different topics like one for security, one for news, one for events.
    3. So we have 1 partial view for RSS, but if the user has 2 RSS gadgets then the same partial view should load with different gadget name. Here the functionality is working fine using foreach loop.

```
 @foreach (var rssFeed in Model.RSSFeedList)
        {
        <article class="bm2014_bigBoxWrap bm2014_bigBoxRSS bm2014_paginate">
            <a href="#" id="btnRefresh" class="bm2014_refreshBtn" rel="external"><img src="~/Content/images/iconRefresh.png" width="20" height="20" alt="refresh icon" title="refresh icon"></a>

            <div class="bm2014_expColCtrl">
                <h1 class="bm2014_bigBoxHdr">
                    <span class="bm2014_hiddenHdr">&nbsp;</span>
                    <!-- for markup validation -->

                   @if (rssFeed.Channel.Name == "xyznews")
                   {
                        <span>@Html.Label(Labels.Title_xyz)</span>
                   }
                   else if(rssFeed.Channel.Category=="xyzRSSFeed")
                   { 
                        <!--<span>@Html.Label(Labels.xyz) - @rssFeed.Channel.Title</span>-->
                        <span>@rssFeed.Channel.Title</span>
                   }

                    <span class="bm2014_expColBtn"><img src="~/Content/images/iconPlus.png" width="32" height="32" alt="expand collapse icon" title="expand collapse icon"></span>
                </h1>
                <div class="bm2014_expColContent bm2014_bellnetRSSWrapper" id="bm2014_divBellnetRSS">
                    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_RSS.cshtml", rssFeed)                   
                </div>

            </div>
        </article>
        }
        <!--  RSS Panel end here -->
```

4. Problem is with refresh issue

if i hit the refresh button for selected gadget, it is by default taking only one RSS name and loading the content irrespective of different gadget selected.

partialview page code-

```
@model Models.RSSFeed

@{
    Layout = null;   
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.multilevelpushmenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-simple-pagination-plugin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    /* scripts to load after the DOM gets ready */
    $(function () {

        offCanvasMenu();        // trigger Javascript controlled OFF canvas menu after AJAX refresh

        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

        $("article.bm2014_bigBoxRSS #btnRefresh").on('click', function (event) {
            var $rssGadgetID = $(this).parents("article.bm2014_paginate").find("div#bm2014_divBellnetRSS");
            var $rssGadgetLdr = $rssGadgetID.find("div#bm2014_gadgetLoader");
            ajaxLoaderHeightCtrl($rssGadgetID, $rssGadgetLdr);

            // AJAX control
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("RefreshBellnetRSS", "Home", new { feedName = Model.Channel.FeedName })',
                contentType: 'application/html; charaset=utf-8',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (result) {
                    $rssGadgetLdr.fadeOut(100, function () {
                        $rssGadgetID.html(result);
                        var moveRSS = $("article.bm2014_bigBoxWrap").css("float");
                        if (moveRSS == "left") {
                            mQueryAJAX("portrait", $rssGadgetID);
                        }
                        else if (moveRSS == "none") {
                            if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)").matches) {
                                mQueryAJAX("portrait", $rssGadgetID);
                            }
                            if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)").matches) {
                                mQueryAJAX("portrait", $rssGadgetID);
                            }
                        }
                        hideTableHeader();
                    });
                },
                error: function (xhr, status) {
                    alert(status);
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>

<div class="bm2014_gadgetLoader" id="bm2014_gadgetLoader" style="display: none;">
    <img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/loaderGadget.gif")' width="48" height="48" alt="ajax loader image" title="ajax loader image">
</div>
<div class="bm2014_strategyContent">
    @if (Model.url != null)
    {            
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th>dummy header - to be hidden</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var url in Model.url)
                {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="@url.URL" rel="external">@url.Name</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }
</div>
```

need help/suggestions

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to have 3 refresh buttons for 3 RSS gadgets e.g. one for security, one for news, one for events.

In the current example, every time you call the code to apply click event, you replace the earlier event and the 'feedname' parameter in url for ajax call also gets updated.

$("article.bm2014_bigBoxRSS #btnRefresh").on('click', function (event) {
......
}

You need to be able to distinguish between the refresh buttons and pass correct parameters. One way is to use data-feedname attribute on your btnRefresh anchor tag (if using HTML5)